# Image hiding from user

Tags: html, css, browser

I want to make a browser game that has users guess some blurred photos of celebrities.The image will be blurred and the user will have a limited amount of time to guess what celebrity is.As time passes the the picture will become clearer.My question is:how can I stop the user from viewing the clear image ?I apply the blurr effect using css3 and send the image to the browser.I think the user can see the image without any effects on it.How can I stop that ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean: if you are happy to accept the fact that anything in the browser can be seen by the user if they really want to, then sure, use CSS and Javascript, probably with a `<canvas>` element. The user will be able to use the browser dev tools to get around it, but if it's just a friendly guessing game, then that's not really a huge issue; just make it so it's not too easy to hack. On the other hand, if it is important that the user can't cheat then you cannot do this purely in the browser; you'll need to do some kind of server-side work as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to implement this is by generating blurred images on the serverside, using encoded unguessable URLs, which are then loading on the client based on a timed update.

There is no way to safely hide something that it already accessible to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your whole approach (e.g. to one where you send multiple images (in different levels of blurriness) one image at a time and use session tokens and a timer to determine which ones a given user is allowed access to), you can't: Any data sent to the browser is accessible to the user. If you sent a clear image and ask the browser to obscure it, then the user will have access to the clear image.

Answer (score 0):

For setting blure image u can use blur value of filter property

here is example http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html